# (Java) Appearing/Disappearing JLabel in a JPanel only disappears on resize

Tags: java, resize, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I'm working in Java, and I have a JPanel in a JFrame. In that JPanel, among other things, I have a JLabel that I want to make appear and disappear at will. I've tried setting visibility to true/false, adding and removing it from the JFrame and JPanel, and, having looked online, I tried validate()ing and revalidate()ing ad infinitum. What can be done here to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried calling repaint() on the JLabel or its parent components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, calling the `setVisible` method is sufficient to make a Swing component to be shown or hidden.

Just to be sure that it works, I tried the following:

```
public class Visibility {
  private void makeGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello");
    final JButton b = new JButton("Hide Label");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        l.setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.getContentPane().add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setSize(200, 200);
    f.setLocation(200, 200);
    f.validate();
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new Visibility().makeGUI();
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

The above program is able to affect the visibility by clicking on a `JButton`.

**Could it be a Threading Issue?**

My next suspicion was that perhaps a `Thread` that is not on the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) may not be affecting the display immediately, so I added the following after initializing the `JLabel` and `JButton`.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      b.setVisible(!b.isVisible());

      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* Handle exception /* }
    }
  }
});

t.start();
```

With the new `Thread` running, it changed the toggled the visibility of the `JLabel` every 100 ms, and this also worked without a problem.

Calling a Swing component off the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is a bad thing, as Swing is not thread-safe. I was a little surprised it worked, and *the fact that it works may just be a fluke*.

**Repaint the `JPanel`?**

If the `JLabel`'s visibility is only being affected on resizing, it probably means that the `JLabel` is being drawn only when the `JPanel` is being repainted.

One thing to try is to call the `JPanel`'s [`repaint`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) method to see if the visibility of the `JLabel` will change.

But this method seems to be just a band-aid to a situation, if the main cause is due to a thread off the EDT is attempting to make changes to the GUI. (Just as a note, the `repaint` method is thread-safe, so it can be called by off-EDT threads, but relying on `repaint` is a workaround than a solution.)

**Try using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`**

Finally, probably the thing I would try is the [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) method, which can be called (and should only be called) from a thread running separate from the EDT, if it wants to affect the GUI.

So, the earlier `Thread` example should be written as:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            b.setVisible(!b.isVisible());
          }
        });
      } catch (Exception e1) { /* Handle exception */ }

      try  {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* Handle exception */ }
    }
  }
});

t.start();
```

If the change to the GUI is indeed occurring on a separate thread, then I would recommend reading [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) in order to find out more information on how to write well-behaving multi-threaded code using Swing.

Answer (score 2):

setVisible() or removing it should work fine, make sure you are doing it from the event dispatch thread though. There are utility methods in EventQueue for running blocks in that thread.

http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-update-my-gui-from-any-thread

You would need to call revalidate() on the parent JPanel if you need its components to be re-laid out.

If you can post an example that demonstrates the problem I can have a look at it for you.